# How can I take a screenshot of my screen and save it on Internal Storage? Android

Tags: java, android

I am implementing a button which lets you take a screenshot, but I want to save it on the Android Internal Storage not in the External Storage (SD Card).

I tried this:

```
private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
     // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {           
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
   // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
          fos.close(); 
    } 
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

I've started this method with an OnClick method of a button:

```
private void takeScreenshot(View v) {

    v = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
   saveToInternalStorage(bitmap)

}
```

But this didn't work. Instead, when I click the button, an error message appears on my cell phone: "Application has stopped".

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * This function captures any Android views to a bitmap shapshot
 * and save it to a file path
 * and optionally open it with android pciture viewer
 */
public void CaptureView(View view, String filePath, boolean bOpen) {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();

        try {
            b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (bOpen) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + filePath), "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

Usage:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path = sdcard + "/demo.jpg";
CaptureView(someViewInstace, path, false);
```

You can use **Context.getFilesDir()** method to get the path to the internal storage:

```
String path = yourActivity.getFilesDir() + "/" + name);
```

Comment: How can I use it? I dont understad the parameters of this method D:

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do the same thing on the Internal Storaga? If im not wrong i think that works with external Storage

Comment: David thanks, I can finally take the screenshot, but i got a new problem, the screenshot is a black screen.

Comment: I done this: 
    View view1 = (View)findViewById(R.id.lay);
    view1.getRootView();
    
    String path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/" + "picture.jpg";
    CaptureView(view1, path, true);

}

Comment: @SEBASTIANSOLERCASTAÑEDA, this is another issue, you'd better start a new post rather than asking different questions in one thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use openFileOutput to get a FileOutputStream, try following the example in the doc https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

What's the error in the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Add permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

add this line manifest file application tag

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

In activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                        REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            } else {

                takeScreenshot();
            }

        }
    });

}

private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //**if you want to open this screenshot
        openScreenshot(imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void openScreenshot(File imageFile) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}